# VCALENDAR .ics file issue

Tags: c#

I have a .ics file that set a calendar ehtry to OutLook 2010 when a end user registers for a course. My server location is on the east coast (orhas EST zone). However, my two regions that the application is for is both in Central Standard Time zone (CST) and Mountain Standard Time zone (MST). My issue is when the calendar entry is set in Outlook if the course startime is  CST and the user is registering from a MST zone the calender entry is set 2 hours ahead of the actual start time. An example is the course starts at 10:30 AM and I register for the course and I am in MST zone. My Outlook calendar entry sets the course to start at 8:30 AM instead of 9:30 AM.
Also, if the course is a MST zone and I am also MST zone the course is set an hour behind the course start time. An example the class in to start at 2:00 PM MST I register for the course and I am also in MST the Outlook calendar entry set the entry at 3:00 PM when it should be 2:00 PM
My code is below:`

```
//create the Body in VCALENDAR format
string calDateFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ";
string bodyCalendar = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nMETHOD:REQUEST\r\nPRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-TZID:11\r\nBEGIN:STANDARD\r\nDTSTART:16010101T020000\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:-0500\r\nTZOFFSETTO:-0600\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU\r\nEND:STANDARD\r\nBEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\nDTSTART:16010101T020000\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:-0600\r\nTZOFFSETTO:-0500\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU\r\nEND:DAYLIGHT\r\nEND:VTIMEZONE\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTAMP:{8}\r\nDTSTART:{0}\r\nSUMMARY:{7}\r\nUID:{5}\r\nATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"{9}\":MAILTO:{9}\r\nACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"{4}\":MAILTO:{4}\r\nORGANIZER;CN=\"{3}\":mailto:{4}\r\nLOCATION:{2}\r\nDTEND:{1}\r\nDESCRIPTION:{7}\\N\r\nSEQUENCE:1\r\nPRIORITY:5\r\nCLASS:\r\nCREATED:{8}\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:{8}\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-1\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-ATTENDEE-CRITICAL-CHANGE:{8}\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNER-CRITICAL-CHANGE:{8}\r\nBEGIN:VALARM\r\nACTION:DISPLAY\r\nDESCRIPTION:REMINDER\r\nTRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT00H15M00S\r\nEND:VALARM\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR\r\n";
bodyCalendar = string.Format(bodyCalendar,
            start.ToUniversalTime().ToString(calDateFormat),
            end.ToUniversalTime().ToString(calDateFormat),
            location,
            organizerName,
            organizerEmail,
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"),
            summary,
            subject,
            DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(calDateFormat),
            attendeeList.ToString());

AlternateView calendarView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyCalendar, calendarType);
calendarView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
msg.AlternateViews.Add(calendarView);
```

And this is my code to offset the eastern time zone:

```
if ((state == "CO" || state == "WY" || state == "MT") && classTimeZone == "MST")
{
    StartDate = StartDate + TimeSpan.Parse("2:00");
    EndDate = EndDate + TimeSpan.Parse("2:00");
}
else if ((state == "CO" || state == "WY" || state == "MT") && classTimeZone == "CST")
{
    StartDate = StartDate + TimeSpan.Parse("1:00");
    EndDate = EndDate + TimeSpan.Parse("1:00");
}
else if ((state == "ND" || state == "SD" || state == "KS" || state == "NE" || state == "MO" || state == "IA") && classTimeZone == "MST")
{
    StartDate = StartDate + TimeSpan.Parse("2:00");
    EndDate = EndDate + TimeSpan.Parse("2:00");
}
else if ((state == "ND" || state == "SD" || state == "KS" || state == "NE" || state == "MO" || state == "IA") && classTimeZone == "CST")
{
    StartDate = StartDate + TimeSpan.Parse("1:00");
    EndDate = EndDate + TimeSpan.Parse("1:00");
}
```

Comment: Holy wall of text, batman. Please look at your post and format it so it isn't so painful to read or look at, people might actually read it.

Comment: Have you considered using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`? It has timezone offset information built-in, so you don't have to perform so much manual (& hardcoded!) timezone translation. SQL Server (if that's your DBMS) also has a corresponding `datetimeoffset` datatype too for data storage purposes.

Comment: I tried the suggetion above and changed the DateTime to DateTimeOffset and no change on the calendar insert. It stills inserts the time two hours before the actual start time for the time zone.